# Actualizar grafico cuando el valor cambia

Tags: ios, swift

He creado 3 `UIView`, cada uno es un gráfico que he utilizado de la librería `PNChart`. Los muestro correctamente todo OK.

El problema viene cuando quiero actualizar el valor. Es decir, si inicialmente el gráfico estaba en `60%` y lo actualizo a `80%` se actualiza pero quiero hacerlo automáticamente. que verifique si el valor ha cambiado y que actualize el % con el nuevo valor.

Lo he intentado con `addTarget` pero no aparece en las propiedades de `PNChart` y no se cómo hacerlo.

CODIGO ACTUALIZADO Y FUNCIONANDO

```
import UIKit
import ALSystemUtilities
import PNChart


    class CPU: UIView {
    var lineChart:PNCircleChart?
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        lineChart = PNCircleChart(frame: CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) , total: 100, current: 0, clockwise: true, shadow: true, shadowColor: UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.95, blue:0.95, alpha:1.0), displayCountingLabel: true, overrideLineWidth: 13)
            lineChart!.strokeColor = UIColor(red:0.42, green:0.79, blue:0.86, alpha:1.0)
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            lineChart!.strokeChart()
            self.addSubview(lineChart!)


            // Añadimos un timer para hacer update cada x tiempo
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: "updateValues", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    func updateValues() {
        lineChart!.updateChartByCurrent(cpu_usage())
        print(cpu_usage())
    }

}
```

Comment: Bogdan, es necesario que incluyas algo de código para saber que estás haciendo y expliques un poco si has intentando algo.

Comment: Bogdan Bienvenido a SO en español, podrias darnos mas detalles de tu problema, con la información actual es dificil que podamos ayudarte, podrias incluir el codigo que dibuja tu grafica

Comment: si ahora edito el post

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, creo que te estás liando con tanta UIView, funciones, etc. Creo que deberías simplificar la implementación tanto como puedas. En este, sentido, te propongo la siguiente alternativa. He simplificado un poco la implementación para que veas como hacerlo:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestChart
//
//  Created by mhergon on 19/1/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Marc Hervera. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import ALSystemUtilities
import PNChart

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var cpuChart: PNCircleChart?
    var ramChart: PNCircleChart?

    var cpuValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            cpuChart?.updateChartByCurrent(cpuValue)
        }
    }
    var ramTotal: Int = ALMemory.totalMemory()
    var ramValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            ramChart?.updateChartByCurrent(ramValue)
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Init
        let cpuFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 240, height: 240)
        if let cpuChart = PNCircleChart(frame: cpuFrame, total: 100, current: cpuValue, clockwise: true) {

            cpuChart.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
            view.addSubview(cpuChart)
            cpuChart.strokeChart()

            self.cpuChart = cpuChart

        }

        let ramFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 260, width: 240, height: 240)
        if let ramChart = PNCircleChart(frame: ramFrame, total: ramTotal, current: ramValue, clockwise: true) {

            ramChart.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            ramChart.displayAnimated = false
            view.addSubview(ramChart)
            ramChart.strokeChart()

            self.ramChart = ramChart
        }

        // Actualizamos la primera vez
        updateValues()

        // Añadimos un timer para hacer update cada x tiempo
        let updateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: "updateValues", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        updateTimer.fire()

    }

    func updateValues() {

        // Procesador
        cpuValue = ALProcessor.cpuUsageForApp()

        // Ram
        ramValue = ALMemory.usedMemory()

    }

}
```

Sobre el tema de actualizar los valores, puede utilizar el observing de variables y con un NSTimer actualizar el valor de la variable, de forma que automáticamente se actualice. En el código tienes como hacerlo.

Comment: No creo que me he liado ya que en el ViewControler tengo un scrollView, un UIImageView y he añadido 3 view por que son 3 estadísticas diferentes.

Comment: El tema es que hacer una subclase de cada chart no es necesario. No hace mas que añadir complejidad a algo muy simple, en ese aspecto decía que te habías liado. ¿Qué te parece el código? ¿alguna duda?

Comment: si me da error cuando llega a : updateTimer.fire()

Comment: 2016-01-19 21:50:23.332 InfoDevice[2459:656782] -[InfoDevice.CPU updateValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13dd2f190
2016-01-19 21:50:23.338 InfoDevice[2459:656782] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[InfoDevice.CPU updateValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13dd2f190'

Comment: Pon el código, pero probablemente es porque tienes una subclase de UIView. Al poner el NSTimer, busca el updateValues en la subclase y no en la clase padre. De ahí que te comentaba la complicación excesiva en como has estructurado la clase